# How can I remove Decimals in nvd3.js graphs?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3.js to generate a pie chart, I've been trying to find a way to remove decimal point like 2.00 to 2 in legends.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to override valueFormat of the chart, e.g:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
 var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value })
  .valueFormat(d3.format(".0f"))
  .showLabels(true);

 d3.select("#chart svg")
    .datum(data)
  .transition().duration(1200)
    .call(chart);

  return chart;
});
```

Here `.valueFormat(d3.format(".0f"))` means:

- `.0`: *precision* of zero (the exact meaning of this depends on which *type* is in use).
- `f`: The *type*; in this case, [Number.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). This means a fixed number of digits (the *precision*) appear after the decimal point, and the number is rounded if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For nvd3 pie chart valueFormat: `d3.format("0f")`, this will work properly.